# Renaming columns of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I came across a solution for renaming the column names of a data.frame:

`names(data) <- c("new_name", "another_new_name")`

Here is an example:

```
empl <- c("Mike", "Steven")
wa <- c(25000, 30000)
data <- data.frame(empl, wa)
data

# now rename the columns of the dataframe
names(data) <- c("employee", "wage")
data
```

Now I am wondering how it is possible to assign a vector to a function-call. The result of `names(data)` is a vector with chars. And it seems that this vector is not linked in any way to the data.frame.

Can anyone enlighten me what the mechanisms are?

### Trying to explain to myself

`names(data) <- c("employee", "wage")`

Looking at the assignment above:

- the left hand side `names(data)` returns a vector with the old column names.
- does this assignment not assign to a vector? Instead of to a dataframe‘s attribute?

Comment: A function can take a vector as argument if that is what you meant `f1 <- function(data, nm1) setNames(data, nm1);
f1(data, c("employee", "wage"))`

Comment: It would be better to add what you would like to do using an example function.

Comment: There are only a few functions, which can on the left side of a assignment. The answer from @SirSaleh describes the details of the interpreter related to this. If you are using RStudio you can see during the search for help for the function **names**: there is a function **names<-**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question I think.
This is how R interpreter works, which calls `Replacement functions`. you can define function `function<-` to set functionality for replacement.

Let I have this function:

```
members_of <- function(x){
  print(x)
}
```

I can call it easily:

```
members = c("foo", "bar", "baz")
members_of(members)
# output
# [1] "foo" "bar" "baz"
```

But lets define `members_of<-` function using **back tick** character and *tmp* and *value* arguments:

```
`members_of<-` = function(tmp, value){
     tmp = value
 }
```

Now I can assign to function call:

```
members = c("foo", "bar", "baz")
# output 
# [1] "foo" "bar" "baz"
#
members_of(members) = c("foo2", "bar2", "baz2")
# Now values of members will be
# members
# [1] "foo2" "bar2" "baz2"
```

Comment: So if I want to look up the definition of `names()` function in RStudio, I need to query ```?`names<-` ```?

Comment: if you try to print using that or this  `print.function(`names<-`)` you get `function (x, value)  .Primitive("names<-")` which means it's probably `c` compiled code and need to view R source code.